# Solana metaplex - how to set Collection Name minted NFT

Tags: solana, metaplex

i created nft by candy machine v2 `sugar`

NFT items and Collection NFT created, but the two were created as separate collections.

cache.json

```
{
 "program": {
 "candyMachine": "ALPiatU6aSCjTPm6kp9W9VZtEyQs743DdV3wBPZPRMUC",
 "candyMachineCreator": "4kQXPWdpFMUjs7Smf6KkmEsmDYLLaKnR91PSutaJREP5",
 "collectionMint": "DMbgZoXfhSqgvgWz1f1zdpRXbiQnxnxyuYzHi7corpRc"
},
"items": {
"-1": {
  "name": "PEOPLE Camera",
  "image_hash": "8f9eaba934afc4b1dc43d0421f7a348167fc9ed5ab631311c110537ca4b32ce5",
  "image_link": "https://justlabs.s3.amazonaws.com/collection.png",
  "metadata_hash": "bbef99a5c1a736f807816508fc11e325fa2397b4d977f1a73e04d3922f43bd0d",
  "metadata_link": "https://justlabs.s3.amazonaws.com/collection.json",
  "onChain": true
},
...otherItems
}
```

CollectionMint is entered in the cache file, and in this state, `sugar mint` was used for minting.
However, when checked through `Solscan` or other explorers, it is set to a different collection.

NFT Link

> https://solscan.io/token/75t6LP9fiPBpi9aXhe1R78PEde43zdPUAxFGANTL3LCW

Collection NFT Link

> https://solscan.io/token/DMbgZoXfhSqgvgWz1f1zdpRXbiQnxnxyuYzHi7corpRc

I tried to `migrate` using `metaboss`, but couldn't solve it. I also put Collection items in the NFT's MetaData, but this also didn't work.

how to set Collection name

Answer (score 0):

if you have the Update Authority wallet that is in your case (6JRTWgk1ngG4jTKS3N4h9866vrut8BgYVM8PLTb9zKBu) you can use the update command to update the metadata of the collection NFT which contains the name you wish to change. Check here for metaboss update [command](https://metaboss.rs/update.html)

Comment: You have the right to update. But what should I update? My NFT link shows Collection as Unknown. What do I need to update to change?

Comment: You need to change the Name using metaboss and the address above is the UA which does that and i assume you have it to do so